# SQL Query not running based on the BETWEEN condition

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.5

I have following SQL Query:

```
SELECT Count(*)

FROM   MyDB.mytable

WHERE date_dt BETWEEN '2013-12-09 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-09 23:59:59'

;
```

When I run the above query, I am getting count of the records of the results presents in the table. For some reason it's ignoring the `BETWEEN` condition I have included. Eventually, I have to use `DELETE` instead of `SELECT` and I would be doing something like the following:

```
DELETE  FROM MyDB.mytable
WHERE date_dt BETWEEN '2013-12-09 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-09 23:59:59'
;
```

Had I used `DELETE`, I would have accidentally deleted all the records from my table. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question showing some sample data.  Also, what is the data type of `date_dt`?

Comment: Datatype is datetime for date_dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get records for a single day (2014-12-09) but your code says for last 366 days. May be i m wrong but it looks like you wanted :

```
 DELETE  FROM MyDB.mytable
  WHERE date_dt BETWEEN '2014-12-09 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-09 23:59:59'
  ;
```

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your query.

Comment: Not really. I think that was the mistake I was doing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Awesome Rocky ! keep rocking mate

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL documentation says:

*"For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE."*

Worth a try.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   MyDB.mytable
WHERE date_dt BETWEEN CAST('2013-12-09 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 
AND CAST('2014-12-09 23:59:59' AS DATETIME);
```